# Gradle equivalent for maven properties

Tags: maven, gradle

How can I add properties in Gradle which are similar to Maven's properties?

The use case is this: I want to have a file which declares all versions for repo dependencies so they are unified in a single place for a multi module project

`compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'`

In Maven you can have properties like this:

```
<properties>
    <jstlVersion>1.2</jstlVersion>
</properties>
```

Is it ok to use Gradle's external properties? Or just add them to the gradle.properties file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project properties defined in the root build file are available to subprojects. So if you have this in your root *build.gradle* file:

```
ext.commonsLangVersion = "2.4"
```

then you can use that in the `dependencies {}` block of a subproject like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "commons-lang:commons-lang:${commonsLangVersion}"
}
```

You can also define such properties in the root *gradle.properties* file instead of the root build file. You use them in the same way.

If you really feel the need to put the versions in a separate file, you can do so. Simply add the following line to the root build file:

```
apply from: "dependencies.gradle"
```

Within the *dependencies.gradle* file, you can define the extra project properties as if they were in the root build file directly:

```
ext.commonsLangVersion = "2.4"
```

**Note** Normally, the values set in the build script take precedence over the values in *gradle.properties*. But if you set a value in the root build script as above, then any matching value in *gradle.properties* will override it *in subprojects*.

This behaviour is somewhat confusing and unique. For behaviour that is consistent with Gradle single-project builds you would need to use the following in the root build script:

```
allprojects {
    apply from: "dependencies.gradle"
}
```

As a general rule of thumb, any given property should be declared/defined in *either* the build script *or* *gradle.properties*. If users want to override a particular property value, they can do so in *$USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties*.

[**EDIT** I have updated the above note to clarify the actual behaviour]

One final thing: Gradle also allows you to control the versions of transitive dependencies via [dependency constraints](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:dependency_constraints). You can also [import Maven BOMs](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#bom-import) if you're using Gradle 4.6 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Found this as a possible solution, though I don't really like that uses relative path to the properties file.

Point 7 from here:
https://proandroiddev.com/make-your-build-gradle-great-again-c84cc172a654#8029